# Displaying all features of datapoint QGIS

Tags: qgis, features

I've got a SHP file with 6000 features and I would like to click on each point on the map and know what the features are for that specific point. It is a lizard database and doing this would tell me all species found at each particular location.

Comment: What's wrong with the identify tool? http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html

Comment: I found right clicking on it did the trick. thanks